# Where should I put the source files?

Tags: linux, kernel, source-code

I am starting to develop a custom kernel modules, so I have the two related organizational questions:

1. Where should I put all my source files? I keep the sources in home directory now `/home/my-name/workspace` and I think it is not a best practice.
2. What path should I deploy my compiled *.ko files to work correctly?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should definitely consider putting the source files into a version control system, that's first priority. Where you put them on your disk is your choice, and the home directory is a good and established position for the files you work with.

The built kernel modules belong into the module path, /lib/modules/${KERNEL_VERSION}. I can't give you much info where exactly there, but they should be loaded in any case.

Comment: I mean where should I put the source files on the disk exactly. I am using `git` as VCS :) For what purposes the `/usr/src` exists?

Comment: This question can be answered by the File System Hierarchy Standard: /usr/src : Source code (optional);
Purpose: Source code may be place placed in this subdirectory, only for reference purposes. So basically it's for source code your distro installed and you can have a look at. It's NOT meant for changing.

Comment: I don't think anything is wrong with ~/workspace